# Different cast in C

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, codeblocks

could you explain the difference between "normal c cast" and "function like c cast"? And how could they be implemented? If I'm not wrong a normal cast, for example between a char and an int would be like this:

```
char a;
int b = 1;

a = (int)b;
```

Thanks

Comment: May I know why do you want to do casting?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm . Check this link

Comment: You could not write an `int`value into `char a`. Your cast make no sense.

Comment: There are no "function like c casts" in C. You're confusing C programming language with **C++**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't have function like casts, C++ does.

The "C style cast" that you showed here is an expilict type conversion performed by the programmer by posing the data type of the expression of specific type is known as explicit type conversion. The explicit type conversion is also known as type casting.

Type casting in c is done in the following form:

```
(int)expression;
```

you can cast it with any valid c data type, and expression may be constant, variable or expression.
it also creates a temporary rvalue which means that using this type of cast on an lvalue may result in a compiler warning/error which is: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: oh wow sorry, just woke up, embarrassing of me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it doesn't have no sense to talk about function-like casting